# how to combine query for multiple able to save data

Tags: php, mysql

can it be combine into 1 query?

this is the query that im trying to combine? or is there a better way to relate these to table?

```
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO orderlist 
(TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)
VALUES ('$transactionID','$itemname','$itemnumber', $ItemTotalPrice,'$itemqty')");

$insert_row1 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO order 
(BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID)
VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID')");
```

when i run these both only one query is functional, so what im trying to do is to make them both works.

im open to any suggestion

Comment: sidenote about `order`, it's a MySQL reserved word and requires special attention.

Comment: so i cant name order for table?

Comment: multi-query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: sure you can use `order`, but you need to wrap it in ticks `\`` otherwise it will throw you a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your second query isn't working is because of the use of `order` and not escaping it; it is a MySQL reserved word:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Sidenote: `ORDER` is used when performing a `SELECT... ORDER BY...`

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Checking for errors would have shown you the syntax error such as:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax near 'order

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Therefore, wrap it in ticks:

```
$insert_row1 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `order` ...
```

or rename your table to something other than a reserved word, say `orders` for example.

If you wish to combine both queries, you can use `multi_query()`

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") || !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1); ";
$sql.= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
?>
```

---

I also need to point out that your present code may be open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) since I do not know if you are escaping your data.

If not, then use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 0):

try to add IF statement.

```
if ($insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO orderlist(TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)VALUES ('$transactionID','$itemname','$itemnumber', $ItemTotalPrice,'$itemqty')"));
{
$insert_row1 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO order (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID) VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID')");
}
```